# How to subsribe to a ROS topic for several seperate times?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a scanlist of 5 positions for the robot to go. And for each position, I hope to subscribe to a topic to get the sensor data and add a marker in the rviz. Here is my code:

```
def addMarkerCallback(msg):
    draw_functions = DrawFunctions('visualisation_marker')
    if msg.data:
        draw_functions.draw_rviz_sphere(0.02)
    else:
        print 'no data'
rospy.init_node("sensor_marker", anonymous = True)

for item in scanlist:    
    moveit_cmd.go(item, wait=True)
    sub1 = rospy.Subscriber('sensor/right', SensorData, addMarkerCallback)   
    rospy.spin()
    print 'go finished'
```

However when I run the code, the problem is the loop will always stay in the first iteration, so the robot will not go to the other positions in the scanlist. I guess it is the problem of rospy.spin(). Could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem...Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191220/how-to-subsribe-to-a-ros-topic-for-several-seperate-times?/) by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have a scanlist of 5 positions for the robot to go. And for each position, I hope to subscribe to a topic to get the sensor data and add a marker in the rviz [..]

This is admittedly more of a design question, but I would argue for a different approach to get to what you want to do.

Essentially, you want to store some data from a sensor, based on the rest of the state of your system (ie: its position relative to some reference position). This to me sounds like a state machine, in which the transitions are taken based on whether or not a position in your *scan list* has been reached.

Going for a [smach](http://wiki.ros.org/smach) state machine might be a bit overkill - a simple `state_` integer member variable in a class would probably be enough.

The sequence of states could be something like: `init -> pre_p1 -> at_pre1 -> post_pre1 -> pre_p2 -> at_p2 -> post_p2 -> ..` etc (I'm assuming your robot is visiting the positions in sequence).
The callback registered for the `sensor/right` topic you are interested in is always active, but only handles incoming messages whenever the state machine is in the right states (so in `at_pN` states). If your program is in the right state, it "*[..] get(s) the sensor data and add(s) a marker in the rviz*", and then immediately transitions to the `post_N` state. In all other states, it does nothing but compare the current `eef` position to the scan list.

The decision to go from `pre_p1` to `at_p1` is dependent on the position of your manipulator's `eef` link. You could probably use MoveIts RobotState class for that, or alternatively, do the FK yourself, based on a `joint_states` topic. Then you update the `state_` variable based on whether the robot is close enough to the current target point in the list.

As your state machine does not define any backward transitions, you probably don't need any filtering on the `eef` position: once you are in state `at_pN` you cannot go back to `pre_pN`. You could however add a proximity threshold which has to be reached before taking the transition to `at_pN`.

PS: for a sensor at 500Hz, it might make sense to disable your `sensor/right` subscriber when you are not in a `at_pN` state. You could use the `pre_pN` and `post_pN` states for that. Then take your measurements in `at_pN`. This would also remove the need to check the `state_` variable in the `sensor/right` callback (as it is only active when needed).

Edit: updated based on clarification by OP in the comments.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-26**:
As a possible refinement, you could just go for 3 states and a counter: `init`, `pre_p`, `at_p` and `scan_list_pointer_`. In `init`, set `scan_list_pointer_ = 0`, go to `pre_p`. Now base transition to `at_p` on proximity to `scan_list[scan_list_pointer_]`. In `at_p`, publish RViz marker, increment `scan_list_pointer_` and transition immediately to `pre_p`. Return, repeat (but now `scan_list[scan_list_pointer_]` points to the next point automatically).

**Comment by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on 2014-08-26**:
Thanks a lot! Actually I am trying to let the robot gripper pass the five positions in the scanlist successively. And the sensor embedded in the finger are giving sensor data continuously in 500Hz. I would like to check the sensor data in each position and draw a marker in the rviz...so do you know how to do that then....Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-27**:
Ah, so `sensor/right` is the sensor data you want to selectively record? I was under the impression that `sensor/right` provided you with a position. I'll update my answer accordingly.